# Code inside async function ignores await property

Tags: javascript, async-await

my problem is in order of execution: the **connectToNewUser** function, which is called inside **wait**() function, get executed before the **myPeer.on('call')**, which is also inside it. I put my code into async\await function, but no result, somehow **"user-connected"** executes first. If I add timeout to **connectToNewUser**

```
socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
    setTimeout(connectToNewUser,1000,userId,stream)
  })
```

, it start to work as I need, but I want to solve it using await. Where is a problem?

```
 const socket = io("/");
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: "/",
    port: "3001"
});

const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;
const peers = {};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}).then(stream => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    wait(myPeer, stream);
});

socket.on("user-disconnected", userId => {
    peers[userId] && peers[userId].close();
});

myPeer.on("open", id => {
    socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
})

const connectToNewUser = (userId, stream) => {
    const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    
    call.on("stream", userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
    });

    call.on("close", () => {
        video.remove();
    });

    peers[userId] = call
}

const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play();
    })

    videoGrid.append(video);
} 

async function wait(myPeer, stream) {
    await myPeer.on("call", call => {
        call.answer(stream);

        const video = document.createElement("video");

        call.on("stream", userVideoStream => {
            addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
    });

    await socket.on("user-connected", userId => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this javascript? If so then I would say that would be an important tag to add.

Comment: you need to wrap the `myPeer.on('call')` by a Promise and resolve it inside the callback.

Comment: Not working. An example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is a tool for managing *promises*.

`await myPeer.on("call",` *doesn't* return a promise so you can't usefully `await` it.

`await myPeer.on("call",` does take a callback so you might be able to [wrap it in a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises). **However…**

Promises are a standard API for handing things that happen asynchronously **once**.

`myPeer.on("call",` looks like it happens **every time** you get a call, which would make it unsuitable for use with promises. If so you should continue to use the callback API it provides (through you might want to look at [RxJs](https://rxjs.dev/) which tries to do for repeated events what Promises do for non-repeated events).

Not everything asynchronous is suitable for use with `await`.

Comment: Looks like you are right) I can fix it using RxJs Scheduler, but it much more comlicated, than simple timeout function. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function waitCall(myPeer) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    myPeer.on("call", call => {
      resolve(call)
    })
  })
}

function waitStream(myPeer){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    myPeer.on("stream", userVideoStream => {
      resolve(userVideoStream)
    })
  })
}

function waitUserConnected(myPeer){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    myPeer.on("user-connected", userId => {
      resolve(userId)
    })
  })
}

async function wait(myPeer, stream){
  const call = await waitCall(myPeer)
  call.answer(stream)
  
  const video = document.createElement("video")
  const userVideoStream = await waitStream(myPeer)
  addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)

  const userId = await waitUserConnected(myPeer)
  connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
}
```